# Android tired with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have extended a fragment named 'DetailFragment' from home activity.But i cannot access the functions of activity in fragment class,like animation,tablayout,and any other functions which i did in activity.But when i change fragment to fragment activity every error getting cleared,But i need fragment only.

Here is my code

```
     public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_detail, container, false);
```

getting error @ 'loadanimation'

```
 Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadein);
            Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadeout);
```

getting error @ 'onTouchEvent'

```
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        return view;
    }
```

}

i need to know that is it possible to work on fragment like we works on activity or is there any functions like 'getActivity' method to access activity class,and how i can implement it. that's enough. thank you in advance programmers..

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 'The method load animation not applicable for DetailFragment',But error getting cleared when i change extends fragment to extends activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you have to do is:
you have to replace all the "this" with "getActivity()"

In activity class pointing to "this" means pointing to the context of the activity.

But as your fragment is nothing but a part of the container of parent activity. In the fragment if you keep "this" it will point to the context of the fragment (not points to the parent activity). thats why you are getting error.

Your problem should be solved by:

```
Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein);
            Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i cannot access the functions of activity in fragment class,like animation,tablayout,and any other functions which i did in activity.
>   You can the activity method using `getActivity()` method

```
((MyActivityClassName)getActivity()).myPublicMethod();
```

Comment: sorry..my question is not like that i don't want access any method from activity.i want to get all the fascilities of activity in fragment too.

Comment: bcoz all the error goes when change extends fragment to extends activity..,But here i need to use fragment.